# When do I want a random intercept model and when a random slope model?

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am performing a meta-regression of nine studies that look at cancer risk vs level of substance in the drinking water.  Each study has a reference strata and one to five higher strata. The studies have quite different ranges of exposure.  I have run the glst program in STATA which is a random slope model, and I have run the Meta-dose program in SAS which is a random intercept model.  My results for fixed models are identical; my results for random model are quite different.  One shows a highly significant positive coefficient and the other shows a non-significant coefficient.  Do I want the random slope model or the random intercept model, and Why?  What are the differences in interpretation?  Is there a model in either program that is both random slope and random intercept?  Why would i want to do that, and how would I do it?

Thanks,  Steve L

Comment: Using a random intercept is a way to model static correlations between measures within group. A random slope is used if you think a covariate's linear affect randomly differs between groups

Comment: Maybe my answer to this question will give some rough idea: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235382/109647

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120964/fixed-effect-vs-random-effect-when-all-possibilities-are-included-in-a-mixed-eff for discussion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed effect vs random effect when all possibilities are included in a mixed effects model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120964/fixed-effect-vs-random-effect-when-all-possibilities-are-included-in-a-mixed-eff)